# Turning while holding a grappled enemy, Action or movement?

Tags: dnd-5e, grapple, forced-movement

So the question here is based on this scenario: I've successfully grappled an enemy.  Now surrounding me is bramble.  If I turn and pull the enemy through the brambles around me, does it cost movement or is it considered an action?

X = Bramble, M = Me, E = Enemy

XX

XME

XX

Answer (score 6):

> When you move, you can drag or carry the Grappled creature with you ...

You need to move - that means you need to change spaces - staying in the same place is **not** moving.

For example, you could move SE -> E -> NW for 15 feet of movement and you end up where they are and they end up in the brambles are N of where you started. Or you could move W -> W for 15 feet of movement (assuming brambles are difficult terrain).

Comment: I see this is a void in the rules. I rule that you can rotate the grappled creature to any location adjacent to you, moving it using normal movement rules, and this movement uses your movement and you spend double what the creature your moving would normally spend to move in that way.

Answer (score 4):

### You Need To Move, Not Just Spin

The rules for grappling describe how you can move a creature that you have grappled (PHB, p. 195):

> **Moving a Grappled Creature.** When you move, you can drag or carry the grappled creature with you, but your speed is halved, unless the creature is two or more sizes smaller than you.

This implies that to move a grappled creature, you must move yourself as well. Rotating in place is not an example of "movement" as defined by the game (i.e. movement which you can do up to your speed). As such, you may only be able to move a grappled creature by moving yourself and dragging the creature along with you.

In your scenario, you might be able to drag yourself through the brambles, and then come out the other side, with the enemy still in the brambles. Then you could move up and down the bramble patch, dragging the enemy with you.

Comment: makes sense, always wanted to grab a goblin and smash him through the surroundings, seems i can't haha

Comment: @CuriosMaximus you can, it's called "shove" or "shove aside", ask your DM

Comment: I don't know where I got this idea, but I've always assumed that during a grapple the entities engaged in a grapple occupy the same space/square, so if this is assumed the diagram in the OP doesn't really make sense.

Comment: @EROgames, although your position doesn't have support in the Rules As Written, I really like that perspective. It prevents some highly problematic situations, where a character with a very high speed can do an obscene amount of damage to a grappled creature without any chance of failure.  It's a house rule I've used myself, but I can't expect any other people to use it.